# Execute all instance of overridden method

Tags: java, oop, object

I am trying to design a simple filtering mechanism, and am looking for the following behavior:

```
public abstract class Filter {
    public abstract boolean doFilter(String comm);

    public boolean filter(List<Filter> col) {
        //return true if all filters ret true, false otherwise
    }
}

public class FilterA extends Filter {
    public boolean doFilter(String comm) {
        if(comm.charAt(0)=='a')
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class FilterB extends Filter {
    public boolean doFilter(String c) {
        return c.length() > 10;
    }
}
```

I have a root Filter class, and many filters that extend it and have their own implementation of the doFilter(String c) method. I then want to be able to call all of the filters doFilter method and go from there. The current way (making the filter method static and calling it with a list of filters + the string to filter seems very clunky.

What could I do if I want to dynamically select which filters based on something else? Say if the String starts with a # i want to use only filters A,E, and F for example. (dynamically set)

thank you

Comment: This looks like a classic use-case for the [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: Yes, it does thank you for that link